# Fastest way to modify columns value iterating on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im using a csv file that has the lap number on a column, where each row contain data about that lap (last number is the lap), like this:
value1, value2, 1
value3, value4, 1
...
valueN, valuex, 99

I have a subset of this data, so i have a range from lapX to lapY, and i want to rearrange it, where lapX is 1 and each time a new lap appears add 1 to the actual lap. I write this code that do what i want:

```
csv = csv file readed as dataframe

lap = 1
lap_file = csv['Trial'][0]

while i < len(csv):
   if csv['Lap'][i] == lap_file:
   csv['Lap'][i] = lap
   i += 1
else:
   lap_file = csv['Lap'][i]
   lap = lap + 1
   csv['Lap'][i] = lap
   i += 1
```

The code does what i need, but it takes a lot of time, i guess because it iterate on each row and the files are kind of big. So, i want to know, is there is another way to do this?

EDIT: Example of my df

what i have:

Race 1:

| id | value1 | value2 | Lap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 5 |
| 2 | c | d | 5 |
| 3 | e | f | 6 |
| 4 | g | h | 6 |
| 5 | i | j | 9 |
| 6 | k | l | 9 |
| 7 | m | n | 9 |

What i want, on a faster way:

Race 1:

| id | value1 | value2 | Lap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 1 |
| 2 | c | d | 1 |
| 3 | e | f | 2 |
| 4 | g | h | 2 |
| 5 | i | j | 3 |
| 6 | k | l | 3 |
| 7 | m | n | 3 |

It's a reference, there's more rows, and i have multiple races, so i could have a Race 2 where the numbers of data per lap is different.

Comment: sample input data and sample required output would help a lot.  I suspect there is a simple solution with `shift()` and no looping

Comment: I thought something like that, but each lap has different quantity of data (lap 1 has more values than lap2, lap2 has less than lap 3 ...)

Comment: I can't visualise what you are trying to describe,  it's not clear to me if you are describing rows only or logic across rows & columns.  Hence why SO best practice is to provide data samples of input and expected output

Comment: I just edited my question and add a reference to the df i have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expected dataframe, it looks like you just want to re-number the laps incrementally, even if they are not consecutive laps. So 5, 6, 9 becomes 1, 2, 3.

For that, take the unique values of `Lap` and sort them. Then zip it with a [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) which just counts up. Make a dictionary from that and then map the old Lap values to new Lap values:

```py
import itertools

lap_map = dict(zip(sorted(df['Lap'].unique()), itertools.count(1)))
# lap_map is {5: 1, 6: 2, 9: 3}

df['Lap'] = df['Lap'].map(lap_map)
df
```

Output:

```
   value1 value2  Lap
id
1      a      b     1
2      c      d     1
3      e      f     2
4      g      h     2
5      i      j     3
6      k      l     3
7      m      n     3
```

Answer (score 0):

- generate a binary series of when lap changes using `shift()`
- `cumsum()` this series (True is equivalent to 1, False to 0)
- a fully vectorised solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 'value1': ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm'],
 'value2': ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'n'],
 'Lap': [5, 5, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9]})

df["Lap"] = (df["Lap"]!=df["Lap"].shift()).cumsum()
```